# Building scala with SBT to make JAR and folder with dependencies

Tags: java, scala, jar, sbt

I have a project in Scala (a kind of test utility) which is currently used only in `sbt run` way. However for certain demo I want to prepare it in a form which does not require `sbt` or `scala` preinstalled (only `JVM`).

First I've tried to use `sbt-assembly` plugin but soon get lost fighting with duplicate entries. So now I'm curious whether I can simply compile it to:

- single `jar`-file containing application itself;
- and `lib` directory containing raw set of dependency jars.

I hope that in such case it would be easy to run with the help of `Main-Class` and `Class-Path: ./lib/*` fields in the manifest - am I wrong? If this is correct, how can I achieve this?

Update: at last I conquered (it seems so) the `sbt-assembly` approach, so now the question is not as urgent (though I'm still curious to extend my knowledge of using sbt).

Comment: What are `duplicate entries`?

Comment: custom settings files like `log4j.xml` and `config.properties` in certain custom libraries, lying directly in the root

Answer (score 0):

When execute `sbt-assembly`, all depedencies, App and resources will package into a single jar file.

You can override config properties in runtime by:

```
java -cp conf/:myAppDemo.jar App.run.mainClass
```

put your **config properties files** in conf folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sbt [one jar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) plugin can resolve more dependency conflicts, then [assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.
Also take a look on merge section of [assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin, that can help you to fix problems like `log4j.xml` duplication. If you have problems with two classes with the same classpath having different content, try to exclude some duplicated dependencies ([library management](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html))